# ¿Se considera acrónimo en castellano, aquel que lo es en otro idioma?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, extranjerismos

He leído varias veces que SQL (Structured Query Language) es un acrónimo, pero si lo traducimos,   en castellano sería "Lenguaje de Consulta Estructurada", con lo que no se trataría de un acrónimo. De traducir el acrónimo directamente diríamos ese-cu-ele. ¿Podríamos decir que es un acrónimo de un anglicismo? ¿Podemos considerar realmente que es un acrónimo en castellano?

Comment: La traducción sería: lenguaje de consulta estructurada (**en el singular**). El nuevo "acrónimo" sería: ele-ce-e sea: LCE No hay s en la forma en castellano. Se dice CAT tool: computer-assisted translation, lo que se traduce por: TAC [computador] o TAO [ordenador] Traducción assistida por ordenador.

Comment: SQL solo es un acrónimo inglés lo suficientemente famoso (específico, inequívoco, frecuente, ...) como para que su equivalente en español no se use, pero no por eso deja de ser un acrónimo inglés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí. De todas formas, SQL se considera un acrónimo en español a pesar de ser un anglicismo.

Principalmente por su uso tan extendido no se usa su versión en español, a diferencia de otros acrónimos o siglas que sí son traducidas, por ejemplo:

UFO: OVNI (objeto volador no identificado)

AIDS: SIDA (síndrome de inmunodeficiencia adquirida)

Sin embargo muchos otros ejemplos, como CAD, COVID, PHP, etc. siguen manteniéndose en su idioma original.